# Printing at different levels in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am from a Java background. In Java you can print at different levels in most frameworks. For example in log4J, you have log levels which can be set to Debug, Info, warn etc.

Does python have anything similar out of the box?  i.e. without having to import another lbrary.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: you will need to `import logging`, but logging is a part of the standard library, and will be installed on the machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep! Have a look at the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module. [Here](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial)'s a tutorial.

Comment: This is a highly useful module. It has saved a lot of bloodshed

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks a million.  Just trying to write good code and this is exactly what I needed.